Can't install TTS on AWS instance t3-large
I'm currently working on a project which need to upload and run a django project on AWS window instance. I have tested this project and run well on my desktop and laptop have no issue at all. However, when I uploaded to AWS I can't install the TTS library which is a requirement for the project. First, I used Python 3.11.9 then I downgraded to 3.10.8 because I heard it is more stable. I also installed C++ v14 with window 11 SDK already. The error appeared when installing Spacy. I try install Spacy alone and it work fine, but it got error when building wheel. My guess is either the SDK version not install correctly or the instance type is not strong enough (I'm currently using t3-large). Have any one encounter this issue please help. Thanks in advance.
    Using cached spacy-3.0.6.tar.gz (7.1 MB)
    Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [164 lines of output]

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          int length


      cdef class Vocab:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      spacy\vocab.pxd:28:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...


      cdef class Vocab:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      spacy\vocab.pxd:29:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...

      cdef class Vocab:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
          cpdef public object vectors
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      spacy\vocab.pxd:30:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      cdef class Vocab:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
          cpdef public object vectors
          cpdef public object _lookups
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      spacy\vocab.pxd:31:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
          cpdef public object vectors
          cpdef public object _lookups
          cpdef public object writing_system
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      spacy\vocab.pxd:32:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          cpdef readonly StringStore strings
          cpdef public Morphology morphology
          cpdef public object vectors
          cpdef public object _lookups
          cpdef public object writing_system
          cpdef public object get_noun_chunks
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      spacy\vocab.pxd:33:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          cdef float prior_prob


      cdef class KnowledgeBase:
          cdef Pool mem
          cpdef readonly Vocab vocab
                ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      spacy\kb.pxd:31:10: Variables cannot be declared with 'cpdef'. Use 'cdef' instead.
      Copied C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-kxff7n82\spacy_67c11f539ddc49f59b8b663ae8274dab\setup.cfg -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-kxff7n82\spacy_67c11f539ddc49f59b8b663ae8274dab\spacy\tests\package
      Copied C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-kxff7n82\spacy_67c11f539ddc49f59b8b663ae8274dab\pyproject.toml -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-kxff7n82\spacy_67c11f539ddc49f59b8b663ae8274dab\spacy\tests\package
      Cythonizing sources
      Compiling spacy/training/example.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/parts_of_speech.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/strings.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/lexeme.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/vocab.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/attrs.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/kb.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/ml/parser_model.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/morphology.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/dep_parser.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/morphologizer.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/multitask.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/ner.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/pipe.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/trainable_pipe.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/sentencizer.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/senter.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/tagger.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/transition_parser.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/arc_eager.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/ner.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/nonproj.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/_state.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/stateclass.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/transition_system.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/pipeline/_parser_internals/_beam_utils.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokenizer.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/training/align.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/training/gold_io.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/doc.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/span.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/token.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/span_group.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/graph.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/morphanalysis.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/tokens/_retokenize.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/matcher/matcher.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/matcher/phrasematcher.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/matcher/dependencymatcher.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/symbols.pyx because it changed.
      Compiling spacy/vectors.pyx because it changed.
      [ 1/41] Cythonizing spacy/attrs.pyx
      [ 2/41] Cythonizing spacy/kb.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-env-qx2w3xqu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 333, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-env-qx2w3xqu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 303, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-env-qx2w3xqu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 319, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 224, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 211, in setup_package
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-env-qx2w3xqu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1154, in cythonize
          cythonize_one(*args)
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-env-qx2w3xqu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1321, in cythonize_one
          raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: spacy/kb.pyx
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


A screenshot of a partial install log doesn't help anyone to help you. Edit your question and paste the actual, complete log, formatting it as code (and delete the screenshot).

Thank you for your advice. I did put the complete log in here

You can find the solution here:https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/12941
In short, you need to use a previous version of cython:
pip install Cython==0.29.36
pip install spacy==3.0.6 --no-build-isolation

